# Cannot extract text from xml in python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file that comes from a doc (MS Word 2003, so I can't use docx library). I'm using lxml to parse it. I can get most of the text (everything is in `<txt>` nodes) but there are some nodes with the following structure:

```
<txt ptr="0x7f6354043000" id="3" symbol="8SwTxtFrm" next="4" upper="2" txtNodeIndex="9">
 <infos>
  <bounds left="1521" top="851" width="10517" height="322"/>
 </infos>
 The text I want to extract    <Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText="" nWidth="2396"/>
 <Text nLength="1" nType="POR_TXT" nHeight="322" nWidth="78"/>
 <Text nLength="42" nType="POR_TXT" nHeight="322" nWidth="5647"/>
 <Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText="" nWidth="2397"/>
 <LineBreak nWidth="10518"/>
 <Finish/>
</txt>
```

When I iter over the `<txt>` to extract the text part with:

```
for txt in tree.iter('txt'):
    print(txt.text)
```

I realized that it's the `<infos>` node that causes the problem. I tried to remove it:

```
for elt in tree.iter('txt'):
for info in elt.findall('infos'):
    elt.remove(info)
```

But this remove the targeted text along with the `<infos>` node, even though it is outside.

Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Try tree.xpath('//text()')

Comment: Thanks Murali, it works perfectly. I don't understand the syntax with the `//`. It is like a `*`?

Comment: yes. its all doc's elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract text this way:

```
In [31]: txt = """<txt ptr="0x7f6354043000" id="3" symbol="8SwTxtFrm" next="4" upper="2" txtNodeIndex="9">
   ....:  <infos>
   ....:   <bounds left="1521" top="851" width="10517" height="322"/>
   ....:  </infos>
   ....:  The text I want to extract    <Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText="" nWidth="2396"/>
   ....:  <Text nLength="1" nType="POR_TXT" nHeight="322" nWidth="78"/>
   ....:  <Text nLength="42" nType="POR_TXT" nHeight="322" nWidth="5647"/>
   ....:  <Special nLength="0" nType="POR_MARGIN" rText="" nWidth="2397"/>
   ....:  <LineBreak nWidth="10518"/>
   ....:  <Finish/>
   ....: </txt>"""

In [32]: node = etree.fromstring(txt)

In [33]: ''.join(node.itertext())
Out[33]: '\n \n  \n \n The text I want to extract    \n \n \n \n \n \n'
```

**UPD:**

Answer suggested by Murali actually returns `list`, so you still need to join strings. And my solution is a little bit faster:

```
In [13]: %timeit ''.join(node.itertext())
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit ''.join(node.xpath('//text()'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It works. I'll use Murali solution that seems slightly simpler. But I take note of the `itertext()` that may be very useful. Tks

Comment: But what exactly was the problem? Is `.iter()` buggy and `.itertext()` not?

Comment: @smci `.iter()` will iterate over nodes (only one `<txt>` in our case), `.itertext()` will iterate over all node's text content. Problem here is in `txt.text`. From lxml doc about `text` property: `Text before the first subelement.` So if you want _all_ text, you should use `.itertext()`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on the Original Post, the OP solved the issue by altering `xpath` as follows

```
tree.xpath('//text()')
```

Comment: Oops  - I see the chain of events here now - sorry it came to me in a review queue (hence stock comment above) but I can see you've done it as a comment first.  I've edited the text to make it a little bolder so that the review queue shouldn't vote it low quality.

Comment: Please explain a little bit why it should work and how it fix the issue.